# Can I enter and leave a Schengen Country if my visa expires over 2 months afterwards?

Tags: schengen

I'm looking to travel into a Schengen country just under three months before my Schengen Visa expires. Is this alright and can I travel right up until the expiration date? I will only be gone maximum 1 week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your visa merely needs to be valid (date of validity, maximum stay and number of entries) for the trip you are planning. The only thing that needs to be valid for more than three months is your passport.

People who travel to the Schengen area for the first time often get visas that only cover the trip they described in their application. The official recommendation from the EU commission is to add a few days to provide some flexibility in case something unexpected happens but not more than that.